# Objective C - iOS, iterate through UILabels within static table cells off screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have a UITableView made of static cells, and each cell contains a UILabel which is populated with field data when the screen loads.  There are more cells than can fit on one screen, so the table view scrolls.  The UILabels are hidden at design-time and I want to set them visible once all the text properties have been set.  I've been using the subviews property of the tableView to iterate through the labels to setHidden:NO  but this only affects the labels within cells that are currently in view.  How can I iterate through all the UILabels regardless of which ones are in view or not?

Thanks
Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can address this issue inside your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Assuming that you have implemented your static cells [the way Apple's guide suggests](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html), your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should look like a sequence of `if-then-else` statements returning the cells provided through `IBOutlet` objects:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    return cell1;
} else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    return cell2;
} // .. and so on
```

Modify this code as follows:

```
UITableViewCell *res = nil;
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    res = cell1;
} else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    res = cell2;
} // .. and so on
// Call your custom code that makes the label visible
if (allTextPropertiesHaveBeenLoaded) {
    [res setMyLabelVisible];
}
return res;
```

When all text properties have been set, call `reloadData` to force all cells to go through your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and get reconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

just call upon the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

```
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfCells; i++) {
UITableView* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i  inSection:0];
}
```

Comment: @Caleb he said he was using static cells